# msg no such element: Unable to locate element:

Tags: selenium

**HTML:**

"Add to cart" object

```
<button class="button spin-button prod-ProductCTA--primary button--primary" data-automation-id="button" data-tl-id="ProductPrimaryCTA-cta_add_to_cart_button" type="button"><span class="button-wrapper"><span class="spin-button-children">Add to cart</span></span></button>
```

"Get in stock alert" object

```
<button class="button spin-button prod-ProductCTA--primary button--primary" data-automation-id="button" data-tl-id="cta_oos_button" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="get in stock alert" role="button" tabindex="0" type="button"><span class="button-wrapper"><span class="spin-button-children">Get in-stock alert</span></span></button>
```

I do not want to click "Add to cart". I just want to store locator info in WebElement "addToCart". Because objects have very identical properties, I chose this unique property "data-tl-id" but did not work.

**Web Driver**

```
WebElement addToCart = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@data-tl-id='ProductPrimaryCTA-cta_add_to_cart_button']"));
```

Below worked for me but both above objects have the same class name so i cant use the class name.

```
WebElement addToCart  = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='button-wrapper']"));
```

I also tried below ways but none worked for me.

```
WebElement addToCart = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Add to cart'"));

WebElement addToCart = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@text,'Add to cart')]"));
```

I get error "No such element: Unable to locate element: ". How to locate the "Add to cart" object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `xpath` is wrong `WebElement addToCart = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Add to cart'"));`

Try below solution

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement webElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[text()='Add to cart']")));
System.out.println("Printing "+webElement.getText());
```

Or you can also try xpath with `contains`

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement webElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Add to cart')]")));
System.out.println("Printing "+webElement.getText());
```

Comment: Both wait statements are just trying to wait for the objects. How can I store it into WebElement "addToCart"?

Comment: Check updated solution you can perform action on a webElement.

Comment: @GreenTree : If your issue is resolved then would you kind enough to accept answer .

Comment: Done. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

since this `xpath` worked for you,

```
WebElement addToCart  = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='button-wrapper']"));
```

Use this to uniquely identify WebElement

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@data-tl-id,'cart')]/span[@class='button-wrapper']"))
```

you can also use this `xpath`

```
//span[contains(text(),'Add to cart')]
```

Comment: This one is the inside `span` tag - `<span class="spin-button-children">Add to cart</span>`. Do you think your `xpath` is correct?

Comment: he is identifying span with @class 'button-wrapper'